# VNC client stuck

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, vnc, amd-graphics

I used "Desktop Sharing" to enable VNC on my machine, I connect to it via "Remmina Remote Desktop Client" on another PC.
I connect to the server, click on "Allow", and my screen shows up fine on the other PC.
However, it does not change... it's frozen. I can, however, see the mouse moving and I can move the mouse from the client (I can also type stuff).

The weird thing is, when I start a LibreOffice Impress slideshow, it does work..

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.3 and I'm using the fglrx drivers

```
david@david-desktop:~$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 5450 
OpenGL version string: 4.5.13399 Compatibility Profile Context 15.201.1151
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found it out myself, changing CaptureMethod to 1, fixed the problem!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)